# How to set and get a datepicker value using antd with formik?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd, formik, yup

Here i am creating Datepicker with antd and passing this antd datepicker to formik field.My sample code for Datepicker with antd

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Form, DatePicker } from "antd"
    import { Field } from "formik";
    import moment from 'moment';

    const FormItem = Form.Item;

    function onChange(date, dateString) {
        console.log(date, dateString);

    }
     const dateFormat = "MM-DD-YYYY"

   // Here i am adding antd error message through DateInput

     const DateInput = ({
            field,
            form: { touched, errors },
            ...props
        }) => {
            const errorMsg = touched[field.name] && errors[field.name]
            const validateStatus = errorMsg ? "error"
                : (touched[field.name] && !errors[field.name]) ? "success"
                    : undefined

            return (
                <div>
                    <FormItem 
                    label={props.label}
                    help={errorMsg}
                    validateStatus={validateStatus}
                    hasFeedback
                   {...props.formitemlayout}>

                    <DatePicker onChange={onChange} defaultPickerValue={moment()}/> 
                    </FormItem>

                </div>
            )
        }
        export default DateInput
```

i am adding this ant component to formik field component,submit the form using handleSubmit and applying the YUP validations. iam getting a problem was submitting the form iam getting the required validation of DatePicker, and problem is selecting the values of DatePicker iam not getting the value and validation message is displayed after submitting the form.

```
  class FormikApollo extends React.Component {

        render() {
            const { values, handleSubmit, setFieldValue } = this.props
            return (
                <div align="center">
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Field
                                    name="username"
                                    label="Name"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Name"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    value={values.username}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout}

                                />
                                <Field
                                    name="email"
                                    label="Email"
                                    placeholder="Enter an Email"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    value={values.email}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout}


                                />

                                <Field
                                    name="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Password"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout}
                                />
                                 <Field
                                    name="dateofbirth"
                                    label="dateOfBirth"
                                    type="date"
                                    component={DateInput}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout}
                                    defaultValue={values.dateofbirth}
                                    format={dateFormat} 

                                />


                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
                     </Form>  
 )
   }

}
```

Here i am getting the values through withFormik and submitting the form using handleSubmit. Why iam not getting datepicker value and why validation message is displayed after selecting a datepicker value?

```
 const FormikApp = (withFormik)({
        mapPropsToValues({ username, email, password, dateofbirth }) {
            return {
                username: username || '',
                email: email || '',
                password: password || '',
                dateofbirth: dateofbirth || ''


            }
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
            username: Yup.string()
                .min(3, "Username must be above 3 characters")
                .required("Username is required"),
            email: Yup.string()
                .email("Invalid Email !!")
                .required("Email is required"),
            password: Yup.string()
                .min(6, "Password must be above 6 characters")
                .required("Password is required"),

            dateofbirth: Yup.string().required("Date is required")



        }),
        handleSubmit(values, { resetForm }) {
            resetForm();
            console.log(values)

        }

    })(FormikApollo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `DateInput` component try to set value with `setFieldValue()` method of Formik whether it is valid or not. I believe you can extract it from via: `form: { touched, errors, setFieldValue }`.

Also check `touched` items in your form, and make sure that you are changing the value of your date field.

Comment: i am setting a value with SetFieldValue but i am not getting the value of datepicker

Comment: Your usage of the setFieldValue function is incorrect. changed it to `onChange={(date, dateString) => setFieldValue('dateofbirth', dateString)}` 

 [Here is my result](https://imgur.com/a/vhVobDK)
 [My codesandbox for](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5v4wnp7l5) . just check datepicker component

Comment: thank you for your valuable information. i am a new of this technology. it's working?Now i am getting idea bout how to setFieldValue of DatePicker. thank you

Comment: i am observing one problem here if we try to set the value values is set after submitting also value is set not reset may i know the reason why its happened? How to solve this?

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand what you mean?

Comment: After submitting a form also datepicker value is not reset why?it's default set a value using setFieldValue? How to Reset it?

Comment: You are not updating Datepicker's value property. Exract values via: `form: { touched, errors, setFieldValue, values }` then set your value to your Datepicker it has value property when you do that it will be cleared when you reset your form values. [Here is Datepicker doc](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#DatePicker). Your datepicker works as uncontrolled at the moment reflect your formik values to your inputs.

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920833/how-to-reset-antd-datepicker-after-submiting-a-value/54926091#54926091