# How to reset antd datepicker after submiting a value?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd, formik, yup

here i am providing my sample example working on codesandbox. How to reset a datepicker value after submitting a form?

```
    state = {
        setFieldValue: ''
    }

    onChange = (setFieldValue) => {
        this.setState({ setFieldValue: null })
      }


    render() {
        const { values, handleSubmit } = this.props
        return (
            <div align="center">
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                             <Field
                                name="dateofbirth"
                                label="dateOfBirth"
                                component={DateInput}
                                formitemlayout={formItemLayout}
                                value={this.state.setFieldValue}
                                onChange={this.onChange}


                            />


                            <Button type="primary" 
          htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
}
```

my working codesandbox link is [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3pv3xkv1w)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set and get a datepicker value using antd with formik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919371/how-to-set-and-get-a-datepicker-value-using-antd-with-formik)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of adding empty strings as it raises a propType error its best to use `null`

```
<DatePicker
  onChange={(date, dateString) =>
    setFieldValue("dateofbirth", dateString)
  }
  value={dateofbirth !== "" ? moment(dateofbirth) : null}
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your Datepicker is not a controlled component. I converted it to a controlled component and date field was reset post form submission.

```js
<DatePicker
  onChange={(date, dateString) =>
    setFieldValue("dateofbirth", dateString)
  }
  value={dateofbirth !== "" ? moment(dateofbirth) : ""}
/>
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/4zn382mylw?fontsize=14)